# Problemas ao executar o DDL em uma ApI rest via JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, api, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Quando vou executar me aprece esse erro:

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table tb-produto (id int8 not null, nome varchar(255), quantidade numeric(19, 2), valor numeric(19, 2), primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement

Classe Principal

```
package com.produtos.apirest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
@EntityScan("com.produtos.apirest.models")

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApirestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApirestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Model

```
package com.produtos.apirest.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="TB-PRODUTO")
public class Produto implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    
    private String nome;
    
    private BigDecimal quantidade;
    
    private BigDecimal valor;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public BigDecimal getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public void setQuantidade(BigDecimal quantidade) {
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(BigDecimal valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
    
    
    

}
```

Aplication properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true


#Banco local - Luiz
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/produtos-apirest
spring.datasource.username=luiz
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Answer (score 0):

Os identificadores no banco de dados não podem conter caracteres inválidos, como neste caso o '-', ou seja, o nome de sua tabela "TB-PRODUTO" é inválido. O nome correto deveria ser "TB_PRODUTO".

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Se sua classe ApirestApplication estiver na raiz do projeto não precisa ter essa configuração @EntityScan("com.produtos.apirest.models")
Pois o Spring irá ler tudo desde que esteja na raiz.

Com relação ao erro que você está tomando pode ser que seja a propriedade abaixo:
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Mude para:

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

mais informações:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-exactly-work-in-spring

Comment: Estava relacionado a resposta a cima , muito obrigado!